# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (setInterval)

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I am making a program that when you click a button an object spins and this code has an errror:

```
function spin(object) {
    setInterval(object.style.transform += "rotate(5deg)", 3000)
}
```

As some additional information, I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Your code is wrong, but it doesn't cause a syntax error when I try it.

Comment: The first argument to `setInterval` should be a function to run every 3 seconds, not an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment, you cannot simply pass an expression to setInterval, only a function.

```js
function spin(object) {
    setInterval(function() {
        object.style.transform += "rotate(5deg)"
    }, 3000);
}

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
spin(el);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
hello
</div>
```

As you can see, this works. **However**, if you look at the code what is happening is that the `rotate` string is appended to the `transform` property each time. Resulting in stuff like this:

```
transform: rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg) rotate(5deg);
```

That's not what you want. Instead, increment only the number *or* use CSS animations.

**Example with incrementing degrees**

```js
function spin(object) {
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    object.style.transform = 'rotate(' + i * 5 + 'deg)';
  }, 3000);
}

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
spin(el);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

**Keyframes (CSS animation) example**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  transform-origin: center center;
  /* (360 / 5 degree steps) * 3s per step = 216s */
  animation: spin linear 216s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` expects parameter 1 to be a function. Try this:

```
function spin(object) {
    setInterval(function(){
        object.style.transform += "rotate(5deg)";
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: A function or a string, like `'object.style.transform += "rotate(5deg)";'`

Comment: And when it's a string, it expects it to be valid Javascript, which it will execute with `eval()`. What's happening is that it's returning the string `rotate(5deg)`, and `5deg` is not a valid variable.